# javascript and asp.net using json

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've question about asp.net and javascript post and get, I know how to get the value from drop down list in asp.net connected to database, but how to send thing to asp.net and asp.net send it back ...

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RFIDConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT neighborhood_name FROM [Neighborhood]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RFIDConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT street_name FROM [Street]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RFIDConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="select * from Street,neighborhood where Street_status='high' and street.neighborhood_id=neighborhood.neighborhood_id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RFIDConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT neighborhood_name FROM [Neighborhood]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                </div>
```

Comment: Where are your form controls? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w.aspx Please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819558/pass-data-from-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly what you are talking about is data binding your sql datasource to the dropdownlist control.

Edit - your question is how to do an asp.net postback from javascript.

for asp.net (not asp.net ajax) you need to call

```
__doPostBack((eventTarget, eventArgument);
```

Where eventTarget is the name of the contrrol you are doing the postback from and eventArgument is additional information - you may need to populate this depending on what the control is supposed to be doing etc.

Comment: How to get query from asp.net ,but you send request from javascript

Comment: Do you want to instigate a postback (asp.net ajax or not) from within javascript ?

Comment: If I want to get result of query in asp.net, I should use this method ,but what should I write in javascript to make it happen?

Comment: I have edited my answer above to say you need to call __doPostBack in your javascript to initiate a postback to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use AJAX requests. Calling asp.net function from javascript depends on browser too, IE uses `ActiveXObject` while Mozilla family uses `XMLHttpRequest`, you'll have to write cross-browser compatible code so I suggest you to use jquery that saves you from writing cross-browser compatible code but to answer your question, here is what I use:

### Javascript:

**Send data to asp.net:**

```
function CallAjax(actionUrl, postData, callbackFunc) {
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject(callbackFunc);
    xmlHttp.open("POST", actionUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHttp.send(postData);

}

function GetXmlHttpObject(handler) {
    var objXmlHttp = null;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        var strName = "Msxml2.XMLHTTP";
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5") >= 0) {
            strName = "Microsoft.XMLHTTP";
        }
        try {
            objXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(strName);
            objXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handler;
            return objXmlHttp;
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Error. Scripting for ActiveX might be disabled");
            return;
        }
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") >= 0) {
        objXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        objXmlHttp.onload = handler;
        objXmlHttp.onerror = handler;
        return objXmlHttp;
    }
}
```

Sample usage of JS function:

```
var catCode = "001";
// GetSubcategories is the name of asp.net WebMethod present at Default.aspx page
// SubCategoryResponse is the name of JS callback function that will receive data from server
CallAjax("Default.aspx/GetSubcategories", catCode, SubCategoryResponse);
```

**Receive data from asp.net:**

```
function SubCategoryResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
        var resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

### ASP.NET:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetSubcategories(ByVal catCode As String) As String
    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    // Get subcategories into subcateg list
    Dim subcateg As IList(Of String())

    Return json.Serialize(subcateg)
End Function
```

Register `System.Web.Extensions` in your markup.

**Markup - Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

### Web.Config:

You may have to set correct httpHandlers and httpModules in web.config for successfull AJAX request/response. See [Configuring ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx)